# Show 10 newest post for each value of a custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I am working on a theme that has a custom post type called `Languages` and it will have a custom taxonomy called `Language` which will act as a category.

Now let's assume my `Language` taxonomy has these 4 values for now, `English`, `French`, `German`, `Spanish`.

I would like to have something like this with this custom taxonomy/category on my sidebar...

**English**
- link to newest post
- link to 2nd newest post
- link to 3rd newest post
- link to 4th newest post
- All the way to the 10th post
**- then a link to View all**

**French**
- link to newest post
- link to 2nd newest post
- link to 3rd newest post
- link to 4th newest post 
- All the way to the 10th post
**- then a link to View all**

**German**
- link to newest post
- link to 2nd newest post
- link to 3rd newest post
- link to 4th newest post 
- All the way to the 10th post
**- then a link to View all**

**Spanish**
- link to newest post
- link to 2nd newest post
- link to 3rd newest post
- link to 4th newest post 
- All the way to the 10th post
**- then a link to View all**

So as you can see, I just need to list all of a certain taxonomy, then under each one show the 10 newest post under that category ande provide a link to the view all page

Please help me do this someone

I know how to set up the taxonomy and custom post type, I just need help getting it to show each one and the 10 newest post for each one in a list like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code runs a foreach loop through each value associated with the language taxonomy then runs a query on that value to get the posts associated with it.

```
$taxonomies = get_categories( array( 'taxonomy' => 'language' ) );

    foreach ( $taxonomies as $tax ) {
        global $post;
        $args = array(
          'language' => $tax->category_nicename,
          'posts_per_page' => 10
          );

          $lang_query = new WP_Query( $args );

          echo $tax->name;
          echo '<ul>';
          while ($lang_query->have_posts() ) : $lang_query->the_post();

            echo '<li><a href="'.the_permalink().' ">' .the_title(). '</a> </li>';

            endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();

            echo '</ul>';
            echo '<a href=" '.get_category_link( $tax->term_id ).'">View all in ' .$tax->name. '</a>';

    }
```

Comment: Awesome thank you, do you think it is a bad idea to hit the DB like that on every page just to build a menu like this?

Comment: WP_Query has some built in caching.  I've only had problems with very large result sets 40K + posts.  The other option is to use get_posts with a foreach loop.